# Possible applications for small photonic cluster-states

Tags: communication, technologies, cluster-states

Assume I have a "resource state generator", enabling me to produce photonic cluster states in arbitrary shape with O(1-10) photons.
Are there any possible applications for such a device in quantum technologies besides quantum computing, e.g., quantum communication or sensing? References will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few!

In terms of quantum communications, anything that can generate two+ entangled photons can be used to implement [quantum key distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_key_distribution), which allows for two parties to communicate in an information-theoretically secure way. Additionally, these can be used to implement a variety of quantum communication protocols like [quantum teleportation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_teleportation), which allows one to send an unknown qubit from one place to another (which could enable some sort of quantum cloud-based computing in future).

In terms of sensing, there are ideas like [quantum illumination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_illumination) and [quantum radar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_radar) that exploit stronger, non-classical correlations between photons to extract more information than is possible classically with less light, which is an exciting direction to probe systems with lots of background noise and/or that are perturbed by higher light intensities.

Comment: Thanks!

Do you know about references that claim for advantage of multiphoton cluster states over simple two- or three-photon cluster states for quantum communication?

Comment: I know a topic of interest is using higher number multi-photon cluster states to distribute entanglement over lossy channels since they're theoretically more protected than GHZ and other states, but I don't have any references to point you to, unfortunately.